# Script install for SLAPD

Tags: bash, ldap, installation

I'm working on a debian 8.
I wish install slapd with a script, without any questions from terminal.
I tried :

```
debconf-set-selections <<< 'slapd/root_password password 123123'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'slapd/root_password_again 123123'
apt-get install slapd ldap-utils -y
```

But the systeme ask me the ldap password

I wish also use :

```
dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

Is it possible ?

Generally, How can i find all questions during a installation in order to use debconf-set-selections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible attributes for `debconf-set-selections` are defined in the `slapd.templates` file in the debian package, together with a description of what the configuration attribute is about.

For slapd on Debian Jessie, you can find the file here: https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-openldap/openldap.git/tree/debian/slapd.templates?h=jessie

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have multiple typos.  The second row lacks the `password` field type specifier and both lines lack the `slapd` package identifier.  You could easily diagnose this with `debconf-set-selections -c`.

http://openstack.prov12n.com/quiet-or-unattended-installing-openldap-on-ubuntu-14-04/ seems to have a current instruction which should work nicely.  I notice with mixed glee and horror that the field names are different from what you are using, too.  Are you using a completely different `slapd` package, or did you just guess at the field names?

Comment: I really try to understand how debconf is supposed to work, in fact i don't find a full tutorial about it. That why I don't know where i'm supposed to find the field name.
I found this code on multiple websites.
Thanks for the link i will test it

Comment: See e.g. https://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/ia64/apbs03.html.en and for the package you are looking at, install it by hand once, and/or examine the `templates` file in the `deb` package.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your script:

```
echo 'slapd/root_password password password' | debconf-set-selections \
  && echo 'slapd/root_password_again password password' | debconf-set-selections \
  && echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
```

Comment: This would perhaps be more natural as a single here document, especially if you need to add `sudo` into the mix.